# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it <IP ADDRESS OF SMTP SERVER GOES HERE>"

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, mvcmailer

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Edition with MVC Mailer to send out email using SMTP. The only thing that is not working is the SMTP address. I get the error message, "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it `<IP ADDRESS OF SMTP SERVER GOES HERE>`". I know the SMTP address that I'm using is correct. Any suggestions as to why I would get this message and how I can fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the firewall turned on? The port 25 is accessible ?

Comment: Comment from @RamonHammerle : Which server would you like to send to? And are you sure that nothing is blocking it? I am making an email verifier at the moment and I read often that McAfee could block it - or even your firewall. So turn it off and try again.

Comment: Check your web.config under MailSettings, I am guessing you literally have "IP ADDRESS OF SMTP SERVER GOES HERE" under the address attribute....